# What libraries are included by default in each Swift file?

Tags: swift, libraries

I'm trying to understand how Swift works as a language.
I understand that certain libraries are not automatically included for a file to use, so you have to import them.

My question is what library or libraries are included by default for each swift file. Is it only the Swift Standard Library, or are there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "What `import` statements are implicit in a Swift file", only this one:

```
import Swift
```

If the question is what Swift language libraries are included in a Swift app, you can open one and see:

[image]

That's more than the standard library; it's also the overlays for various Cocoa frameworks that you might import in code as well, the shims for talking to Objective-C, and so forth.

By the way, starting in Swift 5, none of those libraries will be included in the app; that is sort of the point of Swift 5.